# .exe файл закрывается после запуска

Tags: python

Я использую pyinstaller -F namefile. Он создаёт .exe файл в папке dist, но после того как я пытаюсь его открыть, консоль сразу же закрывается

```
import pyowm
owm = pyowm.OWM('1fcabbcad02ff45decd91818f74d438d', language = 'ru')
question = input ('Какой город? ')

observation = owm.weather_at_place(question)
w = observation.get_weather()
temp = w.get_temperature ('celsius') ['temp']
print ('В ' + question + ' сейчас ' + w.get_detailed_status())
print ('Температура примерно ' + str(temp) + ' градусов цельсия')
if temp < 9:
    print ('Одевайся, там прохладно')
else:
    print ('Ну там не так чтобы уж и сильно холодно, но аккуратнее')
```

Comment: откройте консоль заранее (cmd) и выполняйте в ней, что бы увидеть что он напишет

Comment: или добавьте в конце `input()`. Таким образом перед завершением работы приложение будет ждать ввод чего-нибудь и после этого завершится

Comment: Я это и делаю через cmd. Как я уже написал, файл .exe создаётся. input() как видите итак имеется в коде

Comment: os.system('pause') не помогает

Comment: @Decya
сделайте import traceback
try:
    ваш скрипт
except:
    traceback.print_exc()

Comment: Не помогло. Но я понял, что при запуске он не может подгрузить библиотеку pyowm. Появляется ошибка и сразу закрывается

Comment: Версия Python3.x.x?

Comment: Я согласен с предыдущими пользователями. В конце кода нужно вставить `input()` с любым содержанием.

Answer (score 1):

*Попробуйте вот так собрать*

```
import sys
from win32.win32api import MessageBox
try:
    import pyowm
    owm = pyowm.OWM('1fcabbcad02ff45decd91818f74d438d', language = 'ru')
    question = input ('Какой город? ')

    observation = owm.weather_at_place(question)
    w = observation.get_weather()
    temp = w.get_temperature ('celsius') ['temp']
    print ('В ' + question + ' сейчас ' + w.get_detailed_status())
    print ('Температура примерно ' + str(temp) + ' градусов цельсия')
    if temp < 9:
        print ('Одевайся, там прохладно')
    else:
        print ('Ну там не так чтобы уж и сильно холодно, но аккуратнее')
except Exception:
    import traceback
    exc_type, exc_value, exc_tb = sys.exc_info()
    traceback_exception = traceback.TracebackException(exc_type, exc_value, exc_tb)
    MessageBox(0, ''.join(traceback_exception.format()), "Сообщение об ошибке", 0)
input("Нажмите Enter для выхода")
```

Comment: Если Windows то пробуйте открывать Exe-ник не двойным кликом а через контекстное меню, у меня например при открывании двойным кликом падает а так нормально.

Comment: Я понял, что когда я компилю код в .exe файл, то компилится он через Python 2.7. Я изменил PATH, но он всё равно создаёт его через Python 2.7. Если же ввести Python в консоль, то выводит

Python 3.7.2 (tags/v3.7.2:9a3ffc0492, Dec 23 2018, 23:09:28) [MSC v.1916 64 bit (AMD64)] on win32
Type "help", "copyright", "credits" or "license" for more information.

Но при компиляции:
[code]
C:\Python 3.6\PythonApplication2>pyinstaller -F PythonApplication2
972 INFO: PyInstaller: 3.4
973 INFO: Python: 2.7.16
[code]
и т.д.

Comment: Удали Python 2 в чём проблема?

Answer (score 1):

Можешь просто добавить `input()`. И не важно что введёшь, но пока не нажимаешь Enter, то не закроeтся.

Answer (score 0):

Ты не указал в Pyinstaller'e import'ы. Ты же юзаешь стороннюю либу тут.

```
pyinstaller --noconfirm --onefile --console --hidden-import "pyowm"  "main.py"
```

Comment: пожалуйста, постарайтесь оставлять чуть более развёрнутые ответы. дополнить ответ можно, нажав [edit]